# Rotate 2D numpy array about a specific line

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing, scipy

I am trying to rotate an image about a specific line drawn within the image. Think of the image of a random 2D numpy array. I have two specific points in the array through which I would like to plot a line. I want to rotate the array/image in such a way that this line forms the new x-axis. How do I do it?

Some code explanation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

x = np.linspace(-5,5,8)
y = np.linspace(-25,25,7)

z = np.random.randn(7,8)*0.5
z = z/np.max(z)

z[5,6] = 2; z[1,1] = 2

plt.pcolormesh(x,y,z); plt.colorbar()
```

[image: Output image]

Now I want to draw a line between the the points with maximum z-values and rotate the array such that this line is the new x-axis.

I try this by first getting the end points of the line. These are usually centroids of large z-values and then get the slope of the line of best fit through these points.

```
# get endpoints which lie at the very end of the gaussian distribution
line_endpoints = np.where(z>z.mean()+3*z.std(), 1, 0)
yline, xline = np.nonzero(line_points)
fitline = stats.linregress(x=xline, y=yline)
```

Now, `fitline` gives me the slope and intercept of the best-fit line. How can I rotate the original array `z` using this slope such that the selected end-points form the new x-axis? I want to look at such an image. I checked out scipy docs but couldn't find anything suitable.

Comment: When you talk about rotation, do you mean physically rotate the figure or something else?

Comment: formulate vector v_x from p_0 to p_1, formulate vector v_y normal to v_x, pointing in the one of two directions that you like. make sure both are normalized (unit length). stuff them in an affine matrix. do something sensible with the translation component. apply transform. done. no need to worry about "slopes" or "angles". if you would like that spelled out, let me know. or work on it yourself and post it as an answer. that's fine.

Comment: if you *don't* want your data to be resampled, then you'll need to add detail to your question. for any plotting, it'll be resampled anyway. I don't know if matplotlib can do that on its own. it might.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`scipy.ndimage.rotate()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html) can do that.

Code example:

```
points_above_3_std = z>z.mean()+3*z.std()
idx = np.array(np.where(points_above_3_std))
endpoint_diff = idx[:, 1] - idx[:, 0]
rot_angle = np.degrees(np.arctan2(endpoint_diff[0], endpoint_diff[1]))
print(rot_angle)
z_rot = scipy.ndimage.rotate(z, rot_angle)
plt.imshow(z_rot[::-1])  # Note: flip y axis to get same direction as pcolormesh plot
```

Plot:

[image: rotated plot]

Notes:

- I changed from describing the rotation with slope to describing the rotation with degrees. Slopes don't handle rotations by 90 degrees well (i.e. if it should be rotated by 90 degrees, the slope will be infinite.)
- There are two rotations which satisfy your question. For example, here a 38 degree rotation puts the two points at the same Y coordinate. However, a rotation by -142 degrees, which would turn the graph upside down, also does this.

  If you wanted to make sure that the rotation angle is in the interval [-90, 90], you could add the following code before `rotate()`.

  ```
  rot_angle = (rot_angle + 90) % 180 - 90
  ```